# WPF Paragraph inlines with special characters starting with [ ( {

Tags: wpf

I am constructing a paragraph to be displayed in a Richtextbox. 
However I noticed that when the paragraph text is [ or ( or {, it starts on a new line.

Example when I typed

> Testing {

and the following appears in the Richtext box:

```
Testing 

{
```

CODE:

```
public Paragraph MakeItem1(string text, string firstmsg)
```

{

```
        Paragraph item = new Paragraph();

        if (firstmsg != "")
        {
            Run run11 = new Run(firstmsg);
            run11.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Top;
            item.Inlines.Add(new Bold(run11));
        }

       //THE TEXT CONTAINING THE {([ is in the string text
        Run run1 = new Run(text);
        run1.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Top;
        item.Inlines.Add(run1);

        Line pLine = new Line();
        pLine.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        pLine.Margin = new Thickness(0, 7, 0, 7);
        pLine.Stroke = Brushes.Gray;
        pLine.X2 = 1;
        item.Inlines.Add(pLine);


        return item;
```

}

Does anyone know why i get this behavior for only these characters?

Comment: It might be just me but how is this related to WCF? Also, show some code please.

Comment: My mistake, it's WPF not WCF. i've put the code. Thanks.